# width vs. flex-basis: [width] - elements get expanded?

Tags: css, flexbox, width

My code and image show the problem: I want to have flex items of the same percentage width, that won't get expanded, no matter what.
Overflow of text is avoided by breaking long words, so basically there's no need to expand any items.

Nevertheless in the second example the item containing a very long word is expanded, although I expected that **flex: 0 0 25%;** would do the same like **flex: 0 0 auto;** with a separate **width: 25%;** declared - but obviously it's not. What am I missing here?

And is there a way to achieve this without declaring a percentage width, for cases with an unknown number of items?
(of course the percentage width doesn't make sense in this testcase because of the 400px div, but eventually all widths would of course be flexible, related to the viewport width.)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font: 16px/1.5 Arial, sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}

p {
  padding: 40px 0 3px;
}

div {
  width: 400px;
  background: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  padding: 20px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  background: rgb(222, 222, 222);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

li+li {
  border-left: none;
}

ul#ul1 li {
  width: 25%;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

ul#ul2 li {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
```

```html
<p>width: 25%;<br> flex: 0 0 auto;</p>

<div>
  <ul id="ul1">
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>helloworldhelloworldhelloworld</li>
    <li>hello</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<p>flex: 0 0 25%;</p>

<div>
  <ul id="ul2">
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>helloworldhelloworldhelloworld</li>
    <li>hello</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[this image shows the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGM8j.png)

Comment: No...that's not how flexbox works.

Comment: `width` != `flex-basis` and breaking words required a defined with.

Comment: flex-basis CSS property specifies the **initial** main size of a flex item

Comment: you can do `ul#ul2 li {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 25%;
}` to avoid setting a static width, but almost the same ..

Comment: See the "Browser Bugs" section in the accepted answer in the duplicate. In some cases `flex-basis` won't work, but `width` will.